# How to save multiple similar values to one SQL record

Tags: php, sql, database

Here's my problem...
I am making a client managing interface that saves values to SQL
I am using SQL/PHP/HTML/JQUERY/CSS etc...

Everything is ok when i all the information are entered once for each client.
ie. each client has 1 or 2 phone numbers, one address, etc.

The problem appears when i want to store say multiple receipt numbers of a client.
Or ie. multiple orders of the same client.

I could start with one but through time i might need to store 100.

What is the best practice to do this?

I thought of storing the ID's separated by commas in a single text record in SQL
Then retrieve the values, separate them and serve them.

What is the best way to do such thing?
Also, how can i command SQL to add a value to the end of the existing string instead of updating it?
Can i automatically add a column to sql each time a similar record is needed?

Comment: SQL/PHP/HTML/JQUERY/CSS = PHP. We know what goes along with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could save it as comma separated values but this is very bad practise and ultimately becomes a pain to maintain.

What you need to have here is SQL normalisation.

For example, in the case of Receipts you have two tables, one for the customer, with a unique id field, and one for receipt which has two columns, customer Id and Receipt Number, so a table for your Customer details:

```
Customers:
CustomerId INT
Address TEXT
Email TEXT
```

And another table for receipts:

```
Receipts:
CustomerID INT
ReceiptNum VARCHAR(9)
```

Then to get all the Receipts for that customer,

```
SELECT *
FROM Receipts
WHERE CustomerID = @ID
```

And to add a new receipt:

```
INSERT INTO Receipts (CustomerId, ReceiptNum)
VALUES (@ID, @Receipt)
```

This is a very loose description but I hope it gives you the idea of what you need to do.

Update:

To give you a sample of how this will look, if you have 2 customers in the Customer Table:

```
CustomerId   Address  Email
1            Here     test@test.com
2            There    test2@test.com
```

And customer 1 has 2 receipts, and customer 2 has 3 receipts:

```
CustomerId   ReceiptNum
1            abcdde10
1            qwerty10
2            1234-1234
2            0987-0987
2            abcd-efgh
```

So the idea is that for each extra bit of information, you only need to add another row. That way you can have 1 bit of information for one customer, and 20 for another, but you don't need to define 20 *spare* fields just in case.

Comment: That was my second guess...   
To make sure i understand, on the Receipts table, you suggest having Column names  as: Receipt1, Receipt2, Receipt3 etc.   
Would i have to Pre-creat the columns? or is there some clever trick to tell sql to create a new column at the end, when a new entry is required?   
How about creating a table with Column as: ClientID, ClientID, ClientID, and storing each receipt ID under them?

Comment: Thank you, exactly the advice i needed!

Answer (score 1):

[First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)

Answer (score 0):

Best practice for this would be to have a table of clients that has a client id. Then have tables for receipts or order or whatever else a client may have multiple of. In the receipt table you also specify the client id which acts as a sort of "link" or foreign key to the client table. Then you can construct your queries accordingly to retrieve a list of client receipts